# Implementing copy c'tor in child after deleting in parent in cpp

Tags: c++

In the parent class I have:

```
Parent(const Parent& p) = delete;
```

I want inherit to a child class, and within the class I want to use the default copy c'tor by doing:

```
Child(const Child& c) = default;
```

However I'm getting an error: `"use of deleted function Parent(const Parent&)"`

Why can I not create a default c'tor and is there a way around this?
Thanks!

Comment: An easy workaround would be to declare the parent copy ctor as protected instead of deleted.

Comment: Sounds like dubious design to me. When would one be able to copy a child if one cannot copy the parent?

Comment: Is there a good reason why parent can't have copy ctor? Does it contain something that can't be copied? If not, you should not delete copy ctor. But if such reason exists, then you can write `Child(const Child& c) : Parent() {}`. It will construct a new parent for copied child, but of course it wont copy parent's data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error message is that the default copy constructor calls the base class's copy constructor. Since that's deleted, the compiler can't generate a copy constructor. The solution is to write your own copy constructor for the derived class, and do whatever you think makes sense to construct a "copy" of the base class object.

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation of the Copy Constructor of a derived class will call the Copy Constructor's of its base class...

Quoting relevant sections of the C++ standard draft... *partially reproduced here*:

[[class.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy)

> [13.](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#13) A copy/move constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted
>   is implicitly defined if it is odr-used ([basic.def.odr]) or when it
>   is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

And

> [14.](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#14) The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members. ....

So, you best bet is to manually define the copy constructor of the base class. But its generally not a good design to circumvent the copy constructor of the parent class.

```
class Parent{
public:
    .....
    Parent(const Parent&) = delete;
};


class Child : public Parent {
public:
    .....
    Child(const Child&) /* use c'tor init list here except for base class */
    {
         .....
    }
};
```

Comment: Ctor init list *must* include Parent, but it must call something different than copy ctor, isn't it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Yes.. You are correct .. Example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/978bb0152950ec8f)